# PngFix + :hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-6, hover, pngfix

Anyone seen or used a good script, jQuery or native, that lets you do PNG fix on hover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/